# how can i test void method using google test framework

Tags: c++, googletest

example: I have a void method which just prints the elements of an array.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void PrintNumbers();

int arr[10];

int main(){

        int i;
        int value = 0;

        for(i = 0 ; i<10; i++)
                arr[i] = value++;

         PrintNumbers();

        return 0;
}

PrintNumbers(){

        int i;

        for(i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++)
                cout <<"arr["<< arr[i] << "]" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Where's the definition of `arr[]`?

Comment: Instead of testing a function that only prints to `std::cout` (which should work, otherwise your system is messed ip badly) I suggest that you create a test function which tests the values in the array or vector to make sure they are what's expected.

Comment: @RohanBari   'arr[]' definition is '#include <stdio.h>

void PrintNumbers();

int arr[10];

int main(){

        int i;
        int check;
        int value = 0;

        for(i = 0 ; i<10; i++)
                arr[i] = value++;

         PrintNumbers();


        return 0;
}
'

Comment: `arr[i]` was directly used before assigning a single element. Results will be unexpected.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve].

Comment: this is my actual code but i want to test PrintNumbers() funciton using google test framework.

Comment: Side note: it would be clearer to the reader of this code if the `arr` was a parameter to `PrintNumbers`. Without the function definition (i.e. seeing only the declaration of this method), the user can't tell what numbers will be printed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To have the method tested properly in this case, I'd inject the stream to the method:

```
void PrintNumbers(std::ostream& os = std::cout) {
    int a = 42;
    os << "Expected " << a;
}

TEST(PrintNumbersTest, TestWithStringStream) {
    std::stringstream myStream;
    PrintNumbers(myStream);

    ASSERT_EQ("Expected 42", myStream.str());
}
```

Dependency injection is one of the options here and is widely acceptable. Because of the default argument, the caller doesn't have to change anything.